# Is it possible to fetch data for the nearest interval if data is not present?

Tags: mysql

I have got historical data with me for Stock Symbols .

My question is, is it possible to fetch data for the last nearest possible data in case data is not present for the selected date?

(I am showing data for 1D , 1WEEK , 2WEEK , 1MONTH) and markets will be holidays on saturday and sundays so the interval keeps on changing . (so nearest value matched to the interval )

```
SELECT * from historical_data where symbol_name IN ('WOCKPHARMA','YESBANK') AND 
current_day =  DATE_SUB('2015-12-18', INTERVAL 6 DAY) ;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3693b/24

Comment: Could "nearest" mean "closest previous"?

Comment: closest current date value ...

Comment: @PreethiJain please check my answer which gives closest previous data if the given date is not matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defining nearest as last previous data for the stock :

**query**

```
select *
from historical_data hd
inner join 
(
SELECT symbol_name, max(current_day) as nearest_day
from historical_data 
where symbol_name IN ('WOCKPHARMA','YESBANK') 
AND current_day <= DATE_SUB('2015-12-18', INTERVAL 6 DAY) 
group by symbol_name
) nearest_data
on hd.symbol_name = nearest_data.symbol_name
and hd.current_day = nearest_data.nearest_day
;
```

**output**

```
+-------------+----------------------------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+
| symbol_name |        current_day         | open_val | high_val | low_val | close_val | last_val | prevclose_val | symbol_name |        nearest_day         |
+-------------+----------------------------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+
| WOCKPHARMA  | December, 11 2015 00:00:00 |     1611 | 1620     | 1570.3  | 1581.25   | 1579     | 1602.1        | WOCKPHARMA  | December, 11 2015 00:00:00 |
| YESBANK     | December, 11 2015 00:00:00 |      709 | 713.7    | 672.25  | 680.6     | 683.45   | 707.1         | YESBANK     | December, 11 2015 00:00:00 |
+-------------+----------------------------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3693b/34)**

Comment: Thank you but could you please tell me why its not reuring any rows if i give intreval as 30 days

Comment: because the sample data doesnt contain any data before december and nearest is defined as before..

Comment: @amdixon, if there are records for Dec 18, it should have returned those records. but why it returns Dec 11 data ?   If it does not find any records for 18 th,  it should return 17th.

Comment: @Thanga returns Dec 11 because it is the closes to DATE_SUB('2015-12-18', INTERVAL 6 DAY) ( december 12 )

Comment: @amdixon  That is the query which Preethi Jain  tried and failed. But Interval is not compulsory in query, because her requirement is just to get records of nearest previous dates if current date is not matching

Comment: @Thanga interval is not required, however gives the user option to specify in verbose way. query does not fail. it gives the nearest results on or before DATE_SUB('2015-12-18', INTERVAL 6 DAY). see fiddle

Answer (score 1):

This is the query you want. as i gave 13 dec  which is not existing, it will give the data of 11th which is nearer before

```
SELECT distinct * from historical_data as a 
JOIN (select max(current_day) as maxday 
  from historical_data 
  where current_day <= '2015-12-13' and 
  symbol_name IN ('WOCKPHARMA','YESBANK') 
group by symbol_name) as d 
on d.maxday=a.current_day group by symbol_name;
```

Comment: when there is data for WOCKPHARMA on 11th but no data for YESBANK on this day, this won't give the most recent result for YESBANK

Comment: Yes. It returns the records which is equal or previous to the current date.

Comment: if closest ( to the 13th ) record for YESBANK is on the 10th and the closest for WOCKPHARMA is on the 11th, this query will return only one record for WOCKPHARMA on the 11th

Comment: No. It will return 10th dec yesbank also. Please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a383ab/1

Comment: correct, that part does work. it seems to also report multiple records for WOCKPHARMA in the case that WOCKPHARMA has records on the 11th and 10th and YESBANK only on the 10th. see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f7ff/2)

Comment: @amdixon  Thanks for pointing that out. Now i edited my answer to fix that

Comment: its worth editing your fixed fiddle into your answer

Comment: Yes I did it. Thank you